# In OS X programming, is it okay to change the height of a "Push Button" by changing its "frame" property?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

In OS X app development, the height of a "Push Button" cannot be changed directly. Its height in Xcode is fixed. But, I want to change it. I find that I can change it by writing code that changes its "frame" property. It seems that this works well (I tested it on OS X El Capitan). But, is it okay to do so? Does or will it result in any weird behavior?

Comment: An NSButton with the default style?  I can't get this to work well: even if I override the `frame` (which you shouldn't do -- see below), it only accepts mouse events in the middle area.

Answer (score 2):

You should only do that if you control the frames of your view manually. Changing the frame by hand when using Autolayout or Springs & Struts is not recommended and not needed since the frames are calculated automatically.

The recommended, modern way of changing heights of stuff is by using Autolayout's `height` constraint. You can set it to whatever you want and even make it depend on some other value like your window size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the style of the button from **Push Button** to **Bevel**. Then setting a height constraint works as expected. And it looks the same as I see it.